# what is the difference between onHover: (something) => function(context), and onHover: function(context) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

when I do `onHover: function(context)` it gives me error

but `onHover: (event) => function(context)` works fine.

What is the difference?
Should onHover always have a variable (PointerHoverEvent)?

Comment: yes, it always needs to be function that takes the event. If you are not using the event, just do (_)=>function(context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(context);
```

may return something that `onHover` parameter doesn't want, `onHover` parameter wants a function, in here `onHover: (event) => function(context)` you are giving it what the parameter wants a function,

to give you an idea

```
//this is a function
Function functionWhichReturnsInt = (){return 1;};

//this is function which needs function
void feedMeAFunction(Function food){
  food();
}

//this is a function which needs int
void feedMeAnInt(int food){
  print(food);
}

//we can call the functions like this
//passing a function
feedMeAFunction(functionWhichReturnsInt);
//passing an int
feedMeAnInt(functionWhichReturnsInt());
```